# Grails Controller Edit returns a map?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

When I generate a controller for a domain class named `User` I get this code for the edit action:

```
def edit(Long id) {
    def userInstance = User.get(id)
    if (!userInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [userInstance: userInstance]
}
```

Can someone please explain why this returns `[userInstance: userInstance]`, rather thank just `userInstance`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller returns a map containing the data that you will (presumably) use in your view. The map keys are the names you use to this data from your view. Perhaps it would be a little less confusing if you renamed the map key, e.g.

```
def edit(Long id) {
    def userInstance = User.get(id)
    if (!userInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [user: userInstance]
}
```

To get the id of the `User` in your view, you would use:

```
${user.id}
```

Comment: Okay, so when you name the KEY as userInstance, its not looking at the reference to the userInstance property, but when you use userInstance as the VALUE, it does refer to the property?

Thank you!

Comment: @oxym0r0n the data in the map is always retrieved in the view via the map's key names. The names of the variables used as the map values makes no difference